# sum of the average

Tags: sql, sql-server

working with this subquery and I am doing something wrong were I am not getting the right average in the `LastSixMosAvg`.

```
JOIN
  (SELECT Avg(LastSix) as LastSixMosAvg,id
  FROM (SELECT t.id,Sum(t.total) as LastSix
          FROM table t
          WHERE t.Month Between @6mosStart and @enddate
          group by t.id)t
    Group by id) d
          ON d.ID=a.ID
```

that query yields this results in a particular ID.

```
Month           Total   LastSixMosAvg
Month 1           325   1,367
Month 2            30   1,367
Month 3           330   1,367
Month 4           336   1,367
Month 5           220   1,367
Month 6           126   1,367
```

Instead in the `LasSixMos Avg` I should see `$228`

Comment: Can you let us know what is above the `JOIN`?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  You are clearly confused, because you have the same `group by` column for both subqueries, so the second isn't doing anything.

Comment: if it helps you,the actual value obtained for LastSixMosAvg is the sum of Total.

Comment: Your second group by needs to be by month I believe.

Comment: Your output includes Month, Total, and LastSixMosAvg, but you are not sharing that query in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is averaging the ***sum*** of the Total column.  The sum is 1,367, and it is a constant for each ID, so averaging it correctly returns 1,367.

Try selecting the average of the Total column itself:

```
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT t.ID, Avg(t.Total) as LastSixMosAvg
    FROM MyTable t
    WHERE t.Month Between @6mosStart and @enddate
    GROUP BY t.ID
) d
    ON d.ID = a.ID
```

Example:

```
declare @t table
(
    [ID] int,
    [Month] int,
    Total int,
    primary key clustered([ID], [Month])
)
insert into @t values
(1, 1, 325),
(1, 2, 30),
(1, 3, 330),
(1, 4, 336),
(1, 5, 220),
(1, 6, 127)

declare @6mosStart int = 1, @enddate int = 6
SELECT t.ID, Avg(t.Total) as LastSixMosAvg
FROM @t t
WHERE t.Month Between @6mosStart and @enddate
GROUP BY t.ID

-- Results:
-- ID LastSixMosAvg
-- 1  228
```

Comment: So here's my full query, maybe a different approach is better, but i basically need to get an average of the sum of 'total'SELECT a.ID,Sum(Total) as Total, Month,LastSixMosAvg
FROM v.Revenue a


INNER JOIN

(SELECT Avg(LastSix) as LastSixMosAvg,ID
  FROM (SELECT t.ID,Sum(t.Total) as LastSix
          FROM table t
          WHERE t.Month Between @ 6mosStart and @ enddate
        GROUP BY t.ID)t
GROUP BY ID)d 
    ON d.D=a. ID

GROUP BY a.ID, Month,LastSixMosAvg

Comment: Paul, the issue is that those amount 325,30,330, etc are summarized totals already, if I run an AVG only it'll run the avg of every transaction that make up the summarized amounts.

Comment: Returning the average of the Total column would give you the "last 6 months average total".  Is that not what you want?  Is the Total column not actually a total of transactions?